# How can I assign words from a double pointer to a new array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, function, pointers

My goal is to write a function that counts how many words from a file start with each letter of the alphabet.

Currently, I have a double pointer that stores each word from the file at each index.
I have tried using `strcpy` and just `=` to assign the values from my double pointer to a new char array and then I'd just find the first letters of each word from there, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Function currently:

```
  int alphabetical_word_count(char **words) {
    int w;
    int j;
    int count[26];
    char *mots[5000];
  
    for (w = 0; w < sizeof(words); w++) {   
      *mots[w] = words[w];
//also tried strcpy(*mots[w], words[w]);
      printf("%c\n", *mots[w]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 27; j++) {
      if ((mots[j] ==  65+j) || (mots[j] == 97+j)) {
        count[j]++;
      }
    }
 }
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? You haven't actually told us. You can do `mots[w] = words[w]`

Comment: Why do you need to make a new array of all the words? Just use the original array.

Comment: You need to pass the length of the array as an argument to the function.

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. Use `isalpha()` to test if a character is a letter,  `'A'` instead of `65`, and `'a'` instead of `97`.

Comment: `sizeof(words)` is 4 or 8 (byte size of pointer). Not the number of elements.